# Django app on Heroku: Application Error

Tags: python, django, heroku

Trying to launch a Django web app on Heroku.

Get Application Error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

heroku logs:

```
2014-02-28T01:49:58.706311+00:00 heroku[run.6585]: Starting process with command `rake`
2014-02-28T01:50:01.064056+00:00 heroku[run.6585]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-28T01:50:01.078817+00:00 heroku[run.6585]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-28T01:47:36.064095+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=8dd34dc2-41ee-40ef-b603-e731ba8a6078 fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T01:49:52.192771+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rake` by amy.r.lam@gmail.com
2014-02-28T01:51:19.326151+00:00 heroku[run.7560]: Awaiting client
2014-02-28T01:51:19.358198+00:00 heroku[run.7560]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-28T01:51:19.362731+00:00 heroku[run.7560]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb`
2014-02-28T01:51:21.075401+00:00 heroku[run.7560]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-28T01:51:21.062102+00:00 heroku[run.7560]: Process exited with status 2
2014-02-28T01:51:30.442655+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python mysite/manage.py syncdb` by amy.r.lam@gmail.com
2014-02-28T01:51:36.973260+00:00 heroku[run.9486]: Awaiting client
2014-02-28T01:51:37.100935+00:00 heroku[run.9486]: Starting process with command `python mysite/manage.py syncdb`
2014-02-28T01:52:01.887843+00:00 heroku[run.9486]: Process exited with status 0
2014-02-28T01:49:46.430021+00:00 heroku[run.4760]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-28T01:52:11.589525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=8cd012cf-37cd-424e-8e69-c8463d488d95 fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T01:52:12.020302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=fe3d19e2-af38-46b6-a9f2-2f3e76bd4bff fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T01:52:01.902293+00:00 heroku[run.9486]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-28T01:55:19.056405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`
2014-02-28T01:55:20.491536+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:45860 (2)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.490915+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-28T01:55:20.502381+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-28T01:55:20.520439+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532572+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-02-28T01:55:20.532812+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:20.533000+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-02-28T01:55:20.689228+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-02-28T01:55:20.689360+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:20 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2014-02-28T01:55:21.970445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-02-28T01:55:27.158974+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`
2014-02-28T01:55:28.155161+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-28T01:55:28.156682+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8671 (2)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.156682+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-28T01:55:28.166192+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171442+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171688+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi
2014-02-28T01:55:28.171876+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-02-28T01:55:28.302686+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2014-02-28T01:55:28.301829+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-02-28 01:55:28 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-02-28T01:55:29.730749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-02-28T01:56:03.044535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=1f164238-99f1-4ba8-8761-7269025f0322 fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T01:55:14.121881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T01:55:21.980705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T01:55:21.981905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T01:55:29.742422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T01:59:40.421794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=349cce4c-69af-42ee-a19d-5c35d6713390 fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T01:59:40.682076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=whispering-waters-3343.herokuapp.com request_id=f998d494-1026-45b3-9c44-2cfb19f45b14 fwd="173.164.141.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Can you post your `Procfile` and `wsgi.py`?

Comment: Procfile: `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`

Comment: wsgi.py: Pretty sure hasn't changed from original Django setup. `import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())`

Comment: Can you post the tree structure of you project? According to your wsgi file, your main app is named mysite,not hellodjango.wsgi.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have changed the wsgi.py. Your are using dj_static. Though you should use it on heroku, it is not in the django default wsgi.py.

Comment: @Leonardo.Z You're right, I changed wsgi in Heroku getting started: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django].

Comment: @Leonardo.Z And here is my tree structure: [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3495345/screenshot.png]. Edited Procfile, pushed to GitHub, pushed to Heroku, restart heroku, heroku logs says "ImportError: No module named mysite.wsgi".

Comment: Could you post your manage.py? the `mysite` module is added to the python path by the manager.py. I guess something is wrong with it.

Comment: Besides the gunicorn error, can you run any other django management commands? Like django shell https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#using-the-django-shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be this: "ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi"

From the info you have posted, it sounds like "hellodjango" is not the name of your project and the WSGI application, so the reference to hellodjango.wsgi is failing.

I'm guessing the name should be "mysite" from your project structure and wsgi.py file.

EDIT: Your procfile should call .wsgi (this is the default django behavior).

Please most in the comments what is the project name you used to start this project.

Comment: Comment hidden above - I edited Procfile to web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi, pushed to GitHub, pushed to Heroku, restart heroku, heroku logs says "ImportError: No module named mysite.wsgi". Full heroku logs: (https://gist.github.com/amyrlam/9266660)

Comment: Also here is my foreman start if that is helpful: https://gist.github.com/amyrlam/9266757

Comment: Updated answer, basically, unless you changed this somewhere, you need to call the <project name>.wsgi in the procfile.

Comment: I edited Procfile to `web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi`. Updated heroku logs and foreman start linked to gists in the comments above!

Comment: Is your project name "mysite"?

Comment: Yes, project named mysite. Here is my [heroku logs] (https://gist.github.com/amyrlam/9266660), [foreman start] (https://gist.github.com/amyrlam/9266757) and [folder structure] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3495345/screenshot.png). Let me know if you have any insight, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, so far no luck. Were you able to start the foreman locally originally?

Answer (score 2):

Update the procfile, replacing mysite.wsgi with the proper name of your app, it will will run.

You probably got here through a tutorial, and changing this info was not obvious.

Comment: Please don't post "Thank You" answers.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, in the Procfile I give the name to .wsgi of my core folder, so I named "hellodjango.wsgi", but then in mysite folder I saw in .wsgi file that name must be mysite.wsgi. So i return to Procfile and renamed the hellodjango.wsgi to mysite.wsgi and then Heroku App works perfect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check the name you set in your procfile

web: gunicorn "name".wsgi --log-file -

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).